# User to User live agent chat - no need for case or contact

Tags: liveagent

I have a question regarding the use of the live agent REST api.

I want to create an internal chat between employees. This differs from the classic scenario where a customer is initiating the chat, and thus the need to create a case and relate it to a contact.

Is it possible to start a live agent session, without creating cases and contacts? I just want the transcript to float around by it self.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @andreas86 You might want to try the new beta feature called "Salesforce Anywhere" https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2020/how-to-get-started-with-the-salesforce-anywhere-app. This allows collaboration with real-time chats.Users can chat in the context of their business and share Salesforce records and files to a group, team, or individual

Comment: @identigral i want to test whether or not the concept of a chat is something employees would want to use. Some employees are experts in certain areas and some are not. So the deeper need, is to allow employees to get expert help via some other direct communication channel other than the phone.

Comment: @Swetha thank you, I will look into that.

Comment: @Andreas86 aka Internal Helpdesk. You can [(ab)use the permissions feature](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313408&type=1&mode=1) - it will go through without creating the case. Our customers use chat and/or Chatter to implement Internal Helpdesk. They want to create cases and tie them to contacts of actors (company staff) because they want to record, action, analyze.. whatever issues are raised (+ audit/compliance of a chat record if required).

Comment: @identigral I guess it is an internal helpdesk, yes. We might also need cases to keep track of issues and for reporting - I just wanted to know what options I had. And for me, abusing permissions is not a valid option.